error can't access property "length", prevDeps is undefined with empty array
I have a list of jobs in a store with zustand, when I want to update this with a new selection, if the original table (jobs) already has values it works but if the table is empty it gives me an error:  can't access property "length", prevDeps is undefined  ...?
this is where i call setJobs
createUserJob({
            variables: {
                input: {
                    user_id: id,
                    job_id: filteredJobId || submitJobId
                }
            }
        }).then((response): void => {
            console.log('response', response.data);
            const { createUserJob } = response.data;
            if (createUserJob) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
                const newJob = createUserJob.map((job: any) => ({job_id:job.job_id}));
                console.log('newJob', newJob);
        
                //setNewJob(newJob);
                setJobs(newJob);
            }
            setWishListJob([]);
            
        });

and the zustand store
const [jobs, setJobs] = userDataStore((state) => [state.jobs || [], state.setJobs]);
and this is the console.log of jobs when it is empty and when i have the error
Array []
​
length: 0
​
<prototype>: Array []

I try to put || [] after state.jobs
i try to set sate jobs like that: jobs: [{ job_id: 0}], before it was jobs: [],
i try to use a useEffect to set the store
i try that:
if (jobs.length === 0) {
        setJobs(newJob);
        } else {
        setJobs(newJob);
        }

but still this error just when it is an empty array...

check if the state is initialized with undefined or nothing which again defaults to undefined, and you could put an empty array [] as its starting value ...

Thank you to your answer, i already set it with an empty array:
export const userDataStore = create<UserDataStore>((set) => ({  id: 0,  first_name: '',  last_name: '',  email: '',  address: '',  postal_code: '',  city: '',  siret: '',  denomination: '',  role: '',  jobs: [],
